# Linking issue in QtCreator on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, hyperlink, qt-creator

I need to use port audio in QtCreator. But i can't make the link work.

I have a very simple main:

```
#include "portaudio.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char *[])
{
     std::cout << Pa_GetErrorText(0) << std::endl;
     return 0;
}
```

Il put this snippet in a folder with portaudio.lib.
In Visual Studio 2012, it compile and excute well (after adding the include path and the library).

In QtCreator, i try to add to the .pro:

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD -lportaudio
```

or:

```
LIBS += $$PWD/portaudio.lib
```

So, i'm a litle lost. I'm not very familiar with windows build environement.

I add the compile output.

```
link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:debug\test_portaudio.exe.embed.manifest /OUT:debug\test_portaudio.exe
@C:\Users\victor\AppData\Local\Temp\test_portaudio.exe.7044.16.jom
main.obj : error LNK2019: external symbol Pa_GetErrorText referenced in function main
debug\test_portaudio.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 externes non résolus
jom: C:\Users\victor\Documents\build-test_portaudio-Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\test_portaudio.exe] Error 1120
jom: C:\Users\victor\Documents\build-test_portaudio-Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
09:05:25: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project test_portaudio (kit: Desktop Qt 5.2.0 MSVC2012 64bit)
When executing step 'Make'
```

Thanks for your help,
Vhb

EDIT:
Here is the .pro file:

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui
TARGET = test_portaudio
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../portaudio/include
LIBS += -L$$PWD -lportaudio
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

The manifest file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false' />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*' />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

I'm working on qt 5.2.0 with qtCreator 3.0 and Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Have you rerun qmake because the linker command does not seem to contain your addition? There is an explicit option for executing qmake (rerun).

Comment: I forget to say: yes I did re-run qmake.

Comment: As per my hasty answer, you would need to give us lotta more details. Pleasse provide them.

Comment: Can you please provide more details?

Comment: I totally forgot this post. I fixed it by compiling myself qt from sources using visual studio. I don't realy know why, but it works now. My best guess is that the compiler used to compile Qt is not compatible with Visual Studio 2012 (witch i used to compile the library).
Thanks anyway for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linker command does not seem to have realized the changes:

> link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:debug\test_portaudio.exe.embed.manifest /OUT:debug\test_portaudio.exe

As you can see, there is no reference in there to the portaudio library. It is not surprising that you are getting an undefined reference, then.

You probably forgot to rerun qmake by using the execute qmake option explicitly. Once that is done, it will work.

It is hard to tell more without providing more context, but you could also double check this operation from the command line by using `qmake`. It works here.

Comment: qmake puts most link commands in the response file, which disappears immediately after the command is run, making it difficult to see what exactly is being passed to the linker.

Comment: @rubenvb: it is hard to tell without more context provided, i.e. the project file for one, then the manifest file, qt version, qtcreator version, toolchain version, Visual Studio in question, et al.

Comment: It's not my question ;-)